# Detectar cambio JS en tabla impresa en PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Buen día, soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo, y he investigado lo que aquí cuestionaré y debido a que no lo encuentro es que abro la pregunta:

Tengo una página que carga en la función `$(function(){});` una tabla mediante PHP, es una tabla dinámica cuyos ids cambian según sea el caso, el problema es que cuando intento cachar un cambio en alguno de sus campos no me es posible, ya puse la función `$('#campo').on('change',function(){...});` en la página principal desde donde se llama la función que carga la tabla (una línea abajo).

También intenté imprimir el script después de la impresión de la tabla con la misma variable.

Qué debería hacer para conseguir lo que requiero, de antemano muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Revisa dónde -por ende cuándo- invocas `$().on`, si lo haces antes de llamar al php no agregará el evento a nada. Por otro lado, no es lo mismo agregar el evento al elemento contenedor que a cada uno de los elementos hijo. Si agregas un ejemplo del html generado, tal vez recibas un respuesta concreta.

Answer (score 0):

Para JavaScript Puedes usar esta sintaxis.

```
object.onchange = function(){myScript};
```

Sino prueba usando un EventListener

```
object.addEventListener("change", myScript);
```

Comment: Gracias pero no amigo, supongo es el lugar en el que lo estoy colocando, o porque JS y PHP trabajan en planos distintos, por ejemplo si utilizo el addEventListener, aparece el alert que pongo como script para probar, pero al ver el código de la página, no sale en el input al que se le añadió :/